# C++ adding new objects to a list to avoid implementing destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management

Would it be a good idea to add new objects to a list and returning a pointer to that item to mimic the behavior of the `new` operator? Since the list handles cleanup of objects for us, I wouldn't have to implement a destructor, right?

Edit:
For example, I need to implement a tree data structure, whose nodes would have to be dynamically allocated. I want to avoid the work of traversing the tree in the destructor by using the method I described.

Comment: Hmm..., are you aware that in order to cleanup its content a list will internally call the destructors for all of its contained objects?

Comment: If you write modern idiomatic C++, you almost never need to implement destructors anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The pop operations internally call the destructor of each element. So, you **might** need to care about the destruction. The code piece below is taken directly from the source code of the `std::list`

```
// Erases element at position given.
void _M_erase(iterator __position) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
{
    this->_M_dec_size(1);
    __position._M_node->_M_unhook();
    _Node* __n = static_cast<_Node*>(__position._M_node);
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    _Node_alloc_traits::destroy(_M_get_Node_allocator(), __n->_M_valptr());
#else
    _Tp_alloc_type(_M_get_Node_allocator()).destroy(__n->_M_valptr());
#endif
    _M_put_node(__n);
}
```

As you can see the `_M_erase` function which is called at each time you call the `pop(..)` calls the `destroy(..)` method of the allocator which is currently in use by your list. And, the `destroy(..)` function [calls](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/destroy) the destructor of the given class explicitly.

```
template<typename _Up>
void destroy(_Up* __p) 
{ 
    __p->~_Up(); 
}
```

In conclusion, the `std::list` or any other properly implemented container provides the safe management of resources that are used to contain the objects added to the container. If you have further resources that requires care when its wrapper *(your class in this case)* is being destroyed, then you must implement the destructor explicitly.

Comment: I think I misstated my question. I have a container object which holds a bunch of dynamically allocated nodes, and I want to avoid deleting them one by one. I provided a specific example in my edit.